# Aws amplify S3 upload using angular 2+

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular5

I'm currently working on project where i came to position where i need to upload a image to Aws S3 bucket from localhost using the AWS amplify library..
Im doing exactly the same as this.
`

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', //REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
    },
    Storage: {
        bucket: '', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region
    }
});
```

`

But this approach gives me a CORS issue. Where i'am unable to upload it to S3..
Any help would be appreciated.. Searched a lot but didn't find any of the practical examples of doing it through AWS amplify.. highly appreciate any help thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup CORS policy on your S3 bucket

Here is the doc: https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/storage_guide#setup-amazon-s3-bucket-cors-policy

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```